# How many words makes a memcpy worth it?

Tags: c, performance, code-generation, memcpy

I am generating code where I happen to be copying `n` words from one memory location to another non-overlapping memory location. `n` is known statically.

Currently, I emit a large number of load instructions followed by a large number of store instructions, but I suspect that from a certain value of `n` on, invoking `memcpy` would be faster.

Is there a well-known guideline about how many words you have to copy to make `memcpy` worth a call?

Comment: Often `memcpy` is a compiler intrinsic, which means that if you just always use `memcpy`, the compiler should make this decision for you.

Comment: So I can reasonably use `memcpy` even for copying single words, and can stop worrying?

Comment: So far as I can recall (and it's been a long time since I had to optimise any C code, so I could be misremembering), the compiler will typically replace `memcpy` for (e.g.) a single word with the equivalent inline memory moves (or register copy, or even nothing in some cases).  I'd suggest checking out the generated assembler on a simple test-case to be sure, though.

Comment: "Currently, I emit a large number of load instructions followed by a larger number of store instructions" - wait, why *more* store instructions? And if the stores are only emitted after all loads, where are you loading to? Are you emitting C or assembly?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The compiler I am working on generates C, or LLVM, or assembly… so this was a big vague.

Comment: You can assume LLVM IR, if you want something concrete.

Answer (score 1):

The most optimized code will depend on the architecture of your processor. The data path, register size, number of available data registers and cache are some of the parameters that will determine the most optimized code.

I don't know how your specific compiler will deal with the `memcpy` function, but there are some points that may help you write an optimized copy code:

- Always check the generated assembly code if applicable to know if the current code is the most optimized one.
- If you have n data register free, then load only n value and store them to avoid the need to allocate memory from the stack. Dealing with the registers is much faster than dealing with other memories.
- If your processor have some addressing modes that auto increment the addresses after using them, and if this is what you want to do, then make sure that the generated assembly is doing that.
- Reading contiguous values will improve the cache performance which will give you more optimization.
- As far as you can, try to utilize the full data path with the load and store instructions and if SIMD load and store instructions are available, make sure to use them.